# In process builder, how do I write a formula to set a relative day but a specific time?

Tags: formula, process-builder, formula-field, datetime

In this example, let's say a new account is created and we want to have a kickoff lunch with that new account. I'm setting up my logic in process builder using a Start Date Time set to...

> DATETIMEVALUE( Today() + 3 )

This will only yield today's date plus 3 days. How can I also ensure that it sets the time to noon?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use [DATETIMEVALUE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) and pass Today and Time as Strings.

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(TODAY()) + ' 13:00:00')
```

If you are not in GMT, then things get bit complex. You might have to customize formula according to your [timezone](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181642&language=en_US&type=1).